# Convert unicode characters to utf-8 in python

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

Can someone tell me how to convert unicode characters to utf-8 in python ?

For example :

**Input** - अ अ घ ꗄ

**Output** - E0A485 E0A485 E0A498 EA9784

I tried the following method in python console :

> > *python-prompt*>>> character = "अ"
> >
> > *python-prompt*>>> character
> >
> > *python-prompt*>>> '\xe0\xa4\x85'

In the above example if I simply print the variable "character" in console, I will get '\xe0\xa4\x85' as output. But I need the output in the form of E0A485. In short , the output I got '\xe0\xa4\x85' has 3 '\x' escape characters. How can I get rid of these '\x's ? So that my output is just e0a485 or E0A485

Comment: How do you get the input ? stdin ? a file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `encode()` on your unicode string, then [`hexlify()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html#binascii.hexlify) it.

```
s = u'\u0905 \u0905 \u0918 \ua5c4'
print s
अ अ घ ꗄ
s_utf8 = s.encode('utf8')
print s_utf8
अ अ घ ꗄ
>>> s_utf8
'\xe0\xa4\x85 \xe0\xa4\x85 \xe0\xa4\x98 \xea\x97\x84'
>>> from binascii import hexlify
>>> hexlify(s_utf8)
>>> 'e0a48520e0a48520e0a49820ea9784'
```

If you want to preserve the spaces, you could do this:

```
>>> ' '.join(hexlify(c) for c in s_utf8.split())
'e0a485 e0a485 e0a498 ea9784'
>>> b' '.join(hexlify(c) for c in s_utf8.split())    # Python 3
b'e0a485 e0a485 e0a498 ea9784'
```

Or in one go:

```
>>> s
u'\u0905 \u0905 \u0918 \ua5c4'
>>> ' '.join(hexlify(c.encode('utf8')) for c in s.split())
'e0a485 e0a485 e0a498 ea9784'
>>> b' '.join(hexlify(c.encode('utf8')) for c in s.split())    # Python 3
b'e0a485 e0a485 e0a498 ea9784'
```

You can call `upper()` on the resultant strings to produce `'E0A485 E0A485 E0A498 EA9784'`:

Comment: Hello mhawke. Thanks for the reply :) .. IT WORKS !!! and so simple .. 
Had a question on this in a coding contest and was stuck in this :( .
Anyways Thanks a lot for the answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can use encode with the backslashreplace flag like so:

```
>>> character.encode('ascii', 'backslashreplace')
b'\\u0905 \\u0905 \\u0918 \\ua5c4'
```

And you can always add .upper() if you want it in upper case.